# Using one domain for multiple servers. Is it possible?

Tags: dns, domain-name, subdomain

I am not very familiar with technical DNS setup.

I have this scenario:

- I have one domain, say it is: mydomain.com
- I have multiple servers: each=one ip address

I want to know if it is possible to use the same domain name for all servers, for example: s1.mydomain.com points to server 1's ip, s2.mydomain.com points to server 2's ip...

Comment: Why not just use separate A records pointing to each IP? This isn't very technical.

Comment: What should I put in the host field? Actually there is @ symbol for the main domain

Comment: You would put the subdomain you want (for example `s1` for server 1).........

Comment: Take a look at the following link and you may have a better understand how AD works:https://serverfault.com/questions/402580/what-is-active-directory-domain-services-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the same domain name for all servers?

Yes, but (arguably) this doesn't appear to be what you are asking about. That is, it is possible to have a single domain (e.g. `example.com`) that is serviced by multiple (duplicated) servers.

What you appear to be asking about are [subdomains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain). In short, it is possible to assign separate IPs to separate subdomains in DNS, so that subdomains `s1.example.com`, `s2.example.com`, `s3.example.com` etc. are all serviced by different servers (IP addresses). You simply need an e.g. [A record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) for each subdomain.

> What should I put in the host field?

You don't specify what DNS setup you are using, but typically this would be the subdomain (e.g. `s1`, `s2`, `s3` etc.)

> There is an @ symbol for the main domain.

At least in [BIND](https://www.isc.org/bind/), the `@` symbol is a [shorthand way of referencing the `zone root` or `zone apex`](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/apa/origin.html) (often e.g. `example.com`). This entry is generally necessary. You would add additional A records for each subdomain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using godaddy, ot appears that you have just to put the subdomain part of your subdomain.maindomain.ext and I just did so. I am waiting for the result it appears to take some time.

Comment: I would like to ask two follow up questions:

Comment: Is there a limit for the number of subdomains allowed? Or does it depend on the provider?

Comment: And, is there a way to make the changes take place more faster?

Comment: Any limit on the number of subdomains would depend on the provider (assuming they imposed a limit at all). Regarding making changes "faster", if the DNS provider allows access to the TTL (time-to-live) for the your DNS records, you can reduce this value. Essentially, TTL tells other tells a DNS resolver how long to cache a query before requesting a new one. 1800 seconds (30 minutes) is a common, relatively "quick" default. That said, there is likely no real way to speed up the *initial* record distribution process (i.e. just after you create a subdomain).